# Sockets/4 - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms

Tags: go-ethereum, myetherwallet, websocket

After running for a bit I always get  this with the latest ethereumwallet --fast and latest ubuntu:

```
[2017-07-01 17:00:30.037] [ERROR] ipcProviderBackend - Send request failed Error: Unable to connect to socket: timeout
    at Timeout.setTimeout (/opt/Ethereum Wallet/resources/app.asar/modules/sockets/base.js:97:43)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
[2017-07-01 17:00:30.080] [INFO] Sockets/4 - Connect to {"path":"/home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc"}
[2017-07-01 17:00:30.081] [WARN] Sockets/4 - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...
[2017-07-01 17:00:31.081] [WARN] Sockets/4 - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...
[2017-07-01 17:00:32.082] [WARN] Sockets/4 -
```

Comment: Possibly related issue: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2479?

Comment: Looking at similar issues from the past, it could be that your Node server has crashed/died/disappeared. I'm not entirely sure where they'd be, but could you have a look around for files named `node.log` and `node.log.X` (where `X` is either a number or timestamp [I'm not sure]).

Comment: having the same issue on the win 64 wallet, only thing that seems to help is quitting out and restarting the sync.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11420)